# Proguard error preventing APK from building with "returned error with error code 1"

Tags: android, apk, proguard, eclipse-adt

The issue is when trying to build a signed APK, it errors at the last step with this:

> [2013-06-20 11:39:34 - MyApp] Proguard returned with error code 1. See console
>
> [2013-06-20 11:39:34 - MyApp] Unable to access jarfile /Users/rob/Android

I am using the latest Eclipse ADT v22.0.1-685705 (just installed this morning) and it seems like this issue has been around for at least a month now according to Google.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In order to fix this,

Change:

```
java -jar $PROGUARD_HOME/lib/proguard.jar "$@"
```

To:

```
java -jar "$PROGUARD_HOME/lib/proguard.jar" "$@"
```

in this file `<Android SDK Location Here>/sdk/tools/proguard/bin/proguard.sh`

[Credit here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars&groupby=&sort=&id=55402)