# Proguard returned with error code 1 at the time of apk export

Tags: android, proguard

I am developing Android application using Parse library and many different library projects. For exporting apk file, I am using Pro Guard. While doing the export of the apk file I am receiving the following error:

```
[2015-05-03 20:59:49 - SampleProject] Proguard returned with error code 1. See console
[2015-05-03 20:59:49 - SampleProject] Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider$1: can't find superclass or interface com.facebook.android.Facebook$ServiceListener
[2015-05-03 20:59:49 - SampleProject] Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider$2: can't find superclass or interface com.facebook.Session$StatusCallback
[2015-05-03 20:59:49 - SampleProject] Warning: com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider$2$1: can't find superclass or interface com.facebook.Request$Callback
[2015-05-03 20:59:49 - SampleProject] Warning: org.hamcrest.generator.qdox.ant.AbstractQdoxTask: can't find superclass or interface org.apache.tools.ant.Task
[2015-05-03 20:59:49 - SampleProject] Warning: org.hamcrest.integration.EasyMock2Adapter: can't find superclass or interface org.easymock.IArgumentMatcher
[2015-05-03 20:59:49 - SampleProject] Warning: org.hamcrest.integration.JMock1Adapter: can't find superclass or interface org.jmock.core.Constraint
[2015-05-03 20:59:49 - SampleProject] Warning: com.google.common.base.Equivalence: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
```

Comment: Please check below link.It might help.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17218226/proguard-error-preventing-apk-from-building-with-returned-error-with-error-code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `proguard-project.txt` add this `-dontwarn` and -`keep class` lines:

```
 -keep class com.parse.*{ *; }
 -dontwarn com.parse.**
 -dontwarn com.google.common.**
 -dontwarn org.hamcrest.**
```